# What are Resource Disks in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

What is the definition of a resource disk in Microsoft Azure? I see the term used in the response to my REST call to [get the available Virtual Machine sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-list-sizes-for-resizing). The documentation says that "ResourceDiskSizeInMB" specifies the size in MB of the temporary or resource disk. However I don't see the term resource disk being used anywhere else.

Does this mean that resource disks are the same as temporary disks?

Comment: I've never seen that term anywhere in Azure, so I would be thinking yes, but the easies way to test, create VM with a data disk and do that rest call

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/about-disks-and-vhds?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json - "Temporary Disk"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that resource disks are the same as temporary disks?

You are right, when we list all available virtual machine sizes for a subscription in a location, we will get the information about "**resourceDiskSizeInMb**", it is **Local SSD**(**temporary disk**), we can find it in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs).

[image]

```
{
    "maxDataDiskCount": 2,
    "memoryInMb": 3584,
    "name": "Standard_D1_v2",
    "numberOfCores": 1,
    "osDiskSizeInMb": 1047552,
    "resourceDiskSizeInMb": 51200
  },
```

Comment: There is a nice README on the mounted "Resource Disk" of my Linux VM (mounted at `/mnt/resource`) saying: _"WARNING: THIS IS A TEMPORARY DISK. Any data stored on this drive is SUBJECT TO LOSS and THERE IS NO WAY TO RECOVER IT. Please do not use this disk for storing any personal or application data. For additional details to please refer to the MSDN documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj672979.aspx"_ (I'm missing a colorful Weyland-Yutani Warning Extreme Danger Logo).

Answer (score 3):

The term Resource Disk is used in /etc/waagent.conf.  You can specify a mount point along with filesystem type and a few other options.

Comment: Does a change come into effect when I reboot? All the options in that file seem to make mainly sense at the moment when a VM is created for the first time. Update: Microsoft says _"Restart the WALinuxAgent service by running one of the following commands, depending on the system in question: Ubuntu: service walinuxagent restart  Red Hat/Centos: service waagent restart"_